# SQL -> SELECT query with LIKE statement issue in phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I use the 'sql console' in phpMyAdmin to try out some queries. The following query is working like a charm:

```
Select * from firstTable T1, secondTable T2 Where T2.name = T1.name
```

What I now would like is to have a similar query using the LIKE statement. Unfortunately it is not working. Here below what I tried. Thks in advance. Cheers. Marc.

```
Select * from firstTableb T1, secondTable T2 Where T2.name LIKE "%T1.name%"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you are comparing `t2.name` to the string `%T1.name%`, meaning it literally needs to contain the text `T1.name`.  To search for the actual contents, you need to concatenate in the value:

```
select * from firstTable T1, secondTable T2
 where T2.name like concat('%', T1.name, '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the **Double** quotes with **Single** quotes, and join up the name into the string

```
Select * 
from firstTableb T1 inner join secondTable T2 
on T2.name LIKE concat('%', T1.name, '%')
```

Comment: `'%' + T1.name + '%'` is incorrect method of concatenation in `MySql`.

Comment: you are right mellamokb, I updated the response. besides that, joining tables should be done using the `JOIN` keyword nowadays.

Comment: i use join to make it right. But for the example I chose something that seemed simplier to read (according to me...)